# 2 forms submitting to one database row

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have 2 forms, each one is on a different page, and they both fill information in the same table in the database. Whenever I try to fill them up, the database displays the information as 2 entries, how I can I display the information in the same row in mysqli? 
(first form asks the user to submit first name and last name, second form asks him to submit email and phone number) putting them in one form is not an option.

Comment: The second should be an `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT`.

Comment: On first form submit create (INSERT) a record in a table with name and surname (leaving email, and phone empty), and return its id in the response. Navigate to another page with a second form, use the id to add (UPDATE) additional information to the same record. It can be described in more details and can be done in some different ways. This is just a high-level overview, google will help you xD